# Does the expression $e^\frac{-1}{x^a}$ match any known distribution function?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have the following expression:

$$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^a}\right)\,,$$

where $a$ is a positive constant.

As far as I can see, this is a valid distribution function if we define it to equal $0$ if $x\le0$. Does this match any known cumulative distribution function? What's throwing me off is the $x^a$ in the denominator of the exponent.

Comment: Did you mean "if $x \le 0$" perhaps? If not, you're gonna have a tough time evaluating at $x = 0$.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit it, sorry!

Comment: Doesn't that tend to $1$ as $x$ tends to infinity?

Comment: Yes, it's a cumulative distribution function rather than a probability density function.

Comment: a is positive, I'll edit that in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a>0$ and $x\geq0$,
$$
c(x) = e^{-x^{-a}}
$$
is an increasing function such that $c(0)=0$, $c(x)>0$ for $x>0$ and $c(+\infty) = 1$.
Therefore, it can be interpreted as a CDF, and the relative PDF is 
$$
p(x) = \frac{dc}{dx} =   a e^{-x^{-a}}  x^{-1 - a} 
$$
This may resemble the [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), but it's not. It is the  [Fréchet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution), also known as inverse Weibull distribution. See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/99389.

Comment: Very interesting. I had never heard of this distribution, thanks!